# No output being given when selecting a part of the Google search

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm making a basic "I'm feeling lucky" Python application but when I try to select the link, it returns nothing.

```py
import requests, webbrowser, bs4, sys

print('Googling...')
res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=%s' % sys.argv[1])

if res.status_code != 200:
    print('Invalid input')
    sys.exit()

res = res.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res, features='html.parser')

search = soup.select('.r') # trying to select the class "r"
print(search) # returns "[]"
```

Comment: Please search for the same issue before you ask a question.

Comment: I did, I can't go through every single possible query.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Google sends a redirect page, not a result page. This prevents the system from working.

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: I currently don't know an answer.